# Django form class and view class connected

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Hi in my code(not written by me) i have django form class and views class. I dont know how this is connected each other. Can anyone tell me how this is connected? Also can any one please tell me how this messege : *Credential is in use by {0} collections that are turned on and "
"{1} collections that are turned off. Be mindful that over-using "   "credentials may result in collecting being rate limited by the " "social media API* is displayed, i mean if i need to change the alignment of this text where i should change?

My code classes are :

from forms.py :

```
class CollectionTwitterSearch2Form(BaseCollectionForm):
    incremental = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, required=False, label=INCREMENTAL_LABEL, help_text=INCREMENTAL_HELP)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CollectionTwitterSearch2Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper.layout[0][5].extend(('incremental',))

        if self.instance and self.instance.harvest_options:
            harvest_options = json.loads(self.instance.harvest_options)
            if "incremental" in harvest_options:
                self.fields['incremental'].initial = harvest_options["incremental"]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        m = super(CollectionTwitterSearch2Form, self).save(commit=False)
        m.harvest_type = Collection.TWITTER_SEARCH_2
        harvest_options = {
            "incremental": self.cleaned_data["incremental"],
        }
        m.harvest_options = json.dumps(harvest_options, sort_keys=True)
        m.save()
        return m
```

from views.py :

```
def _get_credential_use_map(credentials, harvest_type):
    credential_use_map = {}
    if harvest_type in Collection.RATE_LIMITED_HARVEST_TYPES:
        for credential in credentials:
            active_collections = 0
            inactive_collections = 0
            for collection in credential.collections.all():
                if collection.is_on:
                    active_collections += 1
                else:
                    inactive_collections += 1
            if active_collections == 0 and inactive_collections == 0:
                credential_use_map[credential.id] = ("", "")
            else:
                credential_use_map[credential.id] = ("warning",
                                                     "Credential is in use by {0} collections that are turned on and "
                                                     "{1} collections that are turned off. Be mindful that over-using "
                                                     "credentials may result in collecting being rate limited by the "
                                                     "social media API.".format(active_collections,
                                                                                inactive_collections))
        return credential_use_map



class CollectionCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CollectionSetOrSuperuserPermissionMixin, SuccessMessageMixin,
                           CreateView):
    model = Collection
    template_name = 'ui/collection_create.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(CollectionCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial["collection_set"] = CollectionSet.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["collection_set_pk"])
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CollectionCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["collection_set"] = CollectionSet.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["collection_set_pk"])
        harvest_type = self.kwargs["harvest_type"]
        context["harvest_type_name"] = _get_harvest_type_name(harvest_type)
        credentials = _get_credential_list(self.kwargs["collection_set_pk"], harvest_type)
        context["credentials"] = credentials
        context["credential_use_map"] = _get_credential_use_map(credentials, harvest_type)
        context["platform"] = Collection.HARVEST_TYPES_TO_PLATFORM[self.kwargs["harvest_type"]]
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CollectionCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["coll"] = self.kwargs["collection_set_pk"]
        kwargs['credential_list'] = _get_credential_list(self.kwargs["collection_set_pk"], self.kwargs["harvest_type"])
        return kwargs

    def get_form_class(self):
        return getattr(forms, _get_collection_form_class(self.kwargs["harvest_type"]))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('collection_detail', args=(self.object.pk,))

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        if self.object.required_seed_count() != 0:
            return "New collection added. You can now add seeds."
        return "New collection added."
```

Full code is here in this git : https://github.com/gwu-libraries/sfm-ui/tree/master/sfm/ui

It would be great anyone can explain how these two classes and template is connected and how the messege is displayed

Answer (score 0):

The CollectionCreateView class is conected to the Form using the function get_form_class, this function is called by default by the CreateView, in there you can see is calling _get_collection_form_class() and as an argument is passing self.kwargs['harvest_type'] this kwargs is comming from the [url declaration](https://github.com/gwu-libraries/sfm-ui/blob/a13dafb2d4033f2a335421d312bc2c3d87827146/sfm/ui/urls.py#L32). The [_get_collection_form_class function](https://github.com/gwu-libraries/sfm-ui/blob/a13dafb2d4033f2a335421d312bc2c3d87827146/sfm/ui/views.py#L377) is returning the CollectionTwitterSearch2Form when the harvest_type is something like TwitterSearch2. The template is given by the `template_name = 'ui/collection_create.html'` again this is the default [vehaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#:%7E:text=would%20cause%20the%20default-,template_name,-to%20be%20%27myapp/author_create_form). And finally for the message this is using [SuccessMessageMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.views.SuccessMessageMixin:%7E:text=class%20views.-,SuccessMessageMixin,-%C2%B6).